# Where does "struct" come from?

Tags: c#

I am trying to understand more deeply values type and System.ValueType

My problem is when I right click on **int** and I click to "go to definition" I go to System.Int32 located in the mscorlib.dll

Now when I right click on **struct** or (enum) and I click to "go to definition", there is an error displayed : "Cannot navigate to 'struct'"

Where does "struct" or "enum" come from ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`int` is an alias for the `System.Int32` type, so it has a Type Definition that you can navigate to.

`struct` and `enum` do not correspond to types; they are merely keywords in the C# language.

Answer (score 7):

`System.Int32` is a type.

Both `struct` and `enum` are keywords rather than types.

As far as `System.ValueType` is concerned, take a look at the documentation:

[MSDN - ValueType Class (System)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.valuetype(v=vs.110).aspx)

It explicitly states that you can't create a class that inherits from `ValueType`. Instead, you have to use one of the types that implicitly inherits from the class using keywords such as `struct` and `enum`.

Comment: To add to this, here are a list of all keywords: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x53a06bb.aspx

Comment: Ok thanks, but when they say value types inherit from System.ValueType, how can I see it ? I need something like :
public something : System.ValueType

Comment: I'm just missing that `int` is an alias for `System.Int32`. Here's a complete list: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ya5y69ds.aspx

Comment: System.Int32 does not inherit from System.ValueType , does it ?

Comment: @Souregi: From [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.valuetype(v=vs.110).aspx): *"Although ValueType is the implicit base class for value types, you cannot create a class that inherits from ValueType directly. Instead, individual compilers provide a language keyword or construct (such as struct in C# and Structure…End Structure in Visual Basic) to support the creation of value types."*

Comment: @Souregi - Take a look at the documentation for the ValueType class: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.valuetype(v=vs.110).aspx It explicitly states that you can't directly inherit from `ValueType`.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting note under the hood, enum refers to [System.Enum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum(v=vs.110).aspx), and all `enum` types derive from this. However, the usage is so specialized, the compiler will not allow you to derive from it directly.

A `struct` type passes by value instead of reference - like passing a non-pointer variable in C#. The nuances of when to use a `struct` or `class` is fairly complex if you don't understand pointers, but basically all value passes are copies, not references to thew original copy.

An `enum` is a class which contains nor more than a finite list of entries or flags, and has a few helper methods from the aformentioned [System.Emum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum(v=vs.110).aspx). This is most useful for things like

```
enum direction { Up, Down, Left, Right }
```

Otherwise, see [Classes and Structs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173109.aspx) and [Enumeration Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc138362(v=vs.110).aspx).